# Error:getLegalSearchEntities$customCriteria1$1$1 is not annotated or on the whitelist

Tags: whitelist, corda

I met a issue based on M13. Please help me to fix it. do you have a common way to add all class into Whitelist?

i used customCriteria as below:

```
val customCriteria1 = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria( builder{ LegalContractSchemaV1.PersistentLegalContractState::contractTitle.equal(test.legalEntity)})
```

this is my whitelist.

```
class AppPlugin: CordaPluginRegistry() {

    override fun customizeSerialization(custom: SerializationCustomization): Boolean {
        custom.apply {
            // OpenGamma classes.
            addToWhitelist(LegalContractSchemaV1.PersistentLegalContractState::class.java)
            addToWhitelist(QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria::class.java)
          //  addToWhitelist(net.corda.core.node.services.vault.

        }
        return true
    }

    override val requiredSchemas: Set<MappedSchema> get() = setOf(com.legalcontract.schema.LegalContractSchemaV1) 
}
```

logs as below:

> Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException:
>   Class
>   com.legalcontract.client.LegalContractClientRPC$getLegalSearchEntities$customCriteria1$1$1
>   is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in
>   serialization Serialization trace: property
>   (net.corda.core.node.services.vault.Column$Kotlin) column
>   (net.corda.core.node.services.vault.CriteriaExpression$ColumnPredicateExpression)
>   expression
>   (net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria$VaultCustomQueryCriteria)
>   b (net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria$AndComposition)
>     at
>   net.corda.core.serialization.CordaClassResolver.checkClass(CordaClassResolver.kt:65)
>     at
>   net.corda.core.serialization.CordaClassResolver.getRegistration(CordaClassResolver.kt:35)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:488)    at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.RPCKryo.getRegistration(RPCStructures.kt:74)    at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:97)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:540)     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:76)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:66)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)    at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:66)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)    at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:66)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)    at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:66)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
>     at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt.serialize(Kryo.kt:169)   at
>   net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt$serialize$1.execute(Kryo.kt:151)
>     at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt$serialize$1.execute(Kryo.kt)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61)
>     at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt.serialize(Kryo.kt:151)   at
>   net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt.serialize$default(Kryo.kt:150)    at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ClientToServer$RpcRequest.writeToClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:103)
>     at
>   net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:197)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.vaultQueryByCriteria(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.legalcontract.client.LegalContractClientRPC.getLegalSearchEntities(LegalContractClientRPC.kt:106)
>     at
>   com.legalcontract.client.LegalContractClientRPC.main(LegalContractClientRPC.kt:68)
>     at
>   com.legalcontract.client.LegalContractClientRPCKt.main(LegalContractClientRPC.kt:39)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug with M13, whereby the whitelist is not loaded correctly for RPC. M14, due for release today, will address this issue.